# Can two people work on the same javascript project simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

me and my friend have this develop a game in 18 hour competition on friday, and we have to use javascript (I don't know why) and it isn't very pleasant to work on the same project from two computers and exchange code over a network share folder, is there any way to have a sort of Google docs for javascript coding? Where we can both edit the same document in real time from two different computers? Any time appreciated.

Comment: Tried using Cloud9 IDE?

Comment: [GitHub](http://github.com)

Comment: I like the git answer, but you may also want to tell us about your operating system, editor and what kind of webserver (or node.js) you are going to be using.  Also, are you on a LAN together or are you collaborating over the internet?  That way, people are more likely to give you answers that are applicable.  But, git is definitely applicable and version control is a need to have.

Comment: https://floobits.com/ - You could try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to "version control".

A good tool (usually the de-facto) for that is [Git](https://git-scm.com/).

You can then push your code to something like [GitHub](http://www.github.com).

Lots of stuff you can do with this... You can both have individual branches, push them to GitHub, and then "diff" them, meaning you can see individual changes line-by-line and decide what you want to keep or discard. These can be merged to, say, a master branch which represents your final product.

Comment: @BinkyNichols After you learn the basics of creating a repo, etc, here is a good workflow for a two person quick project: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow

Comment: The question specifically asked for real time editing. While this enables collaboration and is a key development practice, it doesn't really solve the asker's pain point around process overhead.

Answer (score 0):

use some sort of source control! Github is an excellent site to use GIT with. Other options include, but are not limited to, SVN and mecurial

Answer (score 0):

SVN, GitHub, TFS are good tools for source control. They will also provide you the ability to check in/check out so that things can be merged in the background. So, if you and your friend are working on the same file and both commit the changes, they would be merged together. However, if you're wanting to see your buddies changes as he types, you're going to need to write something to do this. If you want this type of functionality, there's a cool library out there called signalR (http://signalr.net/). This may be a little overkill but I don't know any text editors out there that will allow you to see someone elses changes as they type. You could probably spin something up with ajax calls but again, that would be overkill and performance would be an issue.